# Open one OneNote document from a doc library will open all of them

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, onenote

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with OneNote.

In a document library (Sharepoint OnPromise 2013), at the same root level, we have 10 different OneNote files (`.one` extension), uploaded by different people.

If I try to open 1 of them from OneNote Desktop, using the File > Open > paste of the direct URL to the file (e.g. https://sharepoint.onpromise.com/doclib/MyNoteBook.one), then OneNote shows me several tabs, and each tab is a different OneNote file from the same document library...

For example in the document library "DocLib" I have those files :

- https://sharepoint.onpromise.com/doclib/MyNoteBook.one
- https://sharepoint.onpromise.com/doclib/OtherNoteBook1.one
- https://sharepoint.onpromise.com/doclib/OtherNoteBook2.one
- https://sharepoint.onpromise.com/doclib/OtherNoteBook3.one

If I open MyNoteBook.one, then I see OtherNoteBook1, OtherNoteBook2 and OtherNoteBook3 as well in the OneNote tabs.

It's not the expected behavior because these files are owned by different teams and it's very confusing to see the notes from other team in their own file.

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After digging, it looks like it's due to a `.onetoc2` file that is also in the same document library. If I delete this file and if I try to open only 1 `.one`  file, then it looks OK (after deleting the OneNote cache).